# Windows 10 (version 1903) mini player window

Tags: windows-10

It appears that the [mini-player that appears on the top-left corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4yzC.png) when I pause sound playback on TIDAL is a new feature of Windows 10, v.1903. I have impression that this feature has completely messed up with the multimedia keys (play/pause, previous/next) of my keyboard:

1. Now the multimedia keys seem to work only when the app that does the playback is in focus
2. Even so, very often the mini-player shows that the resume playback command has been registered but it is not propagated onto the playback app
3. In general, the play/pause behaviour is erratic, hence the abundance of the word "seems/appears" in my question.

Has anyone come across issues with the multimedia keys? Is this Windows mini-player configurable? Can it be altogether disabled?

Comment: May I know why you downvoted this question?

Comment: That is the new Volume Level indicator (and shows some other functions occasionally) and is standard in V1903 and on my Insider V1909 machine. So you need to update your software to work with it. It is working fine on my machines

Comment: My (logitech) keyboard software is up to date. Same goes for the TIDAL app and Windows OS.